# Files opened when I open Word

Tags: macos, microsoft-word-2011

When I open word for first time it opens a bunch of other word documents, probably some of the documents that I used **and closed** last time. Is there anyway to avoid this? I want to open just the file I click.

(I closed the files before close word)

Office 2011, Mac.

Comment: What OS? version of Office?

Comment: version 2011 for mac

Comment: I guessed it was Mac - Windows can't do that ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To prevent an app, one time, from opening previous windows at launch, hold the  <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>  key immediately after you double-click to launch.
- To make it open only the docs you want opened each time, always close unwanted documents before quitting.
- To permanently stop it from opening previously open documents, go to Terminal & type
  `defaults write com.microsoft.Word NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool false`
  then  <kbd>Return⏎</kbd>
- To prevent all apps from reopening windows, go to System Prefs > General : check 'Close windows when quitting an app'